# How to set default value in Autocomplete Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In a React project, I have an Autocomplete component which has country name and its relevant calling codes displayed in drop-down list. When selected on list renders the desired data, but, when refreshed, data is null and doesn't show the default data.

```
const [newValue, setNewValue] = useState({});
const [textToggle, textToggleState] = useState(false);

render(
        <div
          style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
          onClick={() => {
            textToggleState(!textToggle);
          }}
        >
          <h5>+{newValue == null ? "91" : newValue.calling_code}</h5> {/* <-- Value gets null when refreshed */}

        </div>
        {textToggle ? (
          <Autocomplete
            id="size-small-standard"
            size="small"
            options={cities}
            onChange={(event, value) => {
              setNewValue(value);
              textToggleState(!textToggle);
            }}
            autoSelect={true}
            getOptionLabel={(option) =>
              `${option.country}` + `+ ${option.calling_code}`
            }
            renderOption={(option) => (
              <>{`${option.country} + ${option.calling_code}`}</>
            )}
            //defaultValue={cities[98]}
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                variant="standard"
                placeholder="Search your country"
                style={{ width: "40%" }}
              />
            )}
          />
        ) : (
          ""
    )}
)
```

Following is the CodeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-add-only-single-value-from-autocomplete-in-material-ui-forked-tu218

Comment: Looks like the value is not `null` but the empty object `{}` by default. Try making it `null` by default instead, e.g. `useState(null)` instead of `useState({})`.

Comment: How to make it null by default

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a value prop to autocomplete component with the newValue. But newValue is an empty object by default that doesn't exist in the options array you are passing to the autocomplete so it will show `undefined + undefined` in the default case. You can make that null and add null check there in the autocomplete itself or you can assign a value directly in your `useState` So as you are having a check for null and using 91 code so instead you can assign that value to the newValue itself directly. Check the code below I have added the value field here

```
        <Autocomplete
            id="size-small-standard"
            size="small"
            options={cities}
            value={newValue !== null ? newValue : cities[98]}
            onChange={(event, value) => {
              setNewValue(value);
              textToggleState(!textToggle);
            }}
            autoSelect={true}
            getOptionLabel={(option) =>
              `${option.country}` + `+ ${option.calling_code}`
            }
            renderOption={(option) => (
              <>{`${option.country} + ${option.calling_code}`}</>
            )}
            //defaultValue={cities[98]}
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                variant="standard"
                placeholder="Search your country"
                style={{ width: "40%" }}
              />
            )}
          />
```

Or you can just pass newValue to the value field and assign the default value in the newValue useState as shown below

```
const [newValue, setNewValue] = useState(cities[98]);
.
.
.
.
<Autocomplete
            id="size-small-standard"
            size="small"
            options={cities}
            value={newValue}
            onChange={(event, value) => {
              setNewValue(value);
              textToggleState(!textToggle);
            }}
            autoSelect={true}
            getOptionLabel={(option) =>
              `${option.country}` + `+ ${option.calling_code}`
            }
            renderOption={(option) => (
              <>{`${option.country} + ${option.calling_code}`}</>
            )}
            //defaultValue={cities[98]}
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                variant="standard"
                placeholder="Search your country"
                style={{ width: "40%" }}
              />
            )}
          />
```